# Can women venture outside of the house?

Tags: rituals, women

I remember reading one conversation between I think between Draupdi and Rukmini in which one of them was telling the other that women shouldn't be standing on the door or windows of the house. I couldn't find it now.

Also Is there any restriction on women moving outside of the house ? Because just few decades ago, it was the norm , women were not allowed to go outside of the house. i think it is still practiced in villages to a certain extent.
The remnant of this rule can be seen in traditions like - In villages still only men attend any fest (eg- wedding fest). Women don't.
Also the bride weeps at her wedding because she would never ever visit her paternal home and see her mother or father ever again after the wedding, not even on any special occasion.

There was saying that "Women enter into the house on four shoulders (i.e on a Palanquin at the time of marriage) and go outside of the house on four shoulders (i.e at the time of their death).
My mother used to tell me that during her childhood (in village) when she ventured out of the house door even for a fraction of second, her grandfather would severely reprimand her and scold her.

So, Is there any rule in scripture where it is written that women shouldn't be venturing outside of the house ?

Comment: Today women  have freedom to work outside  home. What is the relevance? Thinking of restricting their freedom like in Afghanisthan?

Comment: In the second stanza of Matru Panchakam , it is stated that, Matru Sri Aryaamba had dreamt, her son Shankaracharya was being  clad in the robes of an ascetic, so she had rushed to His Gurukul and wept, The entire Gurukul had wept with her. Matru Sri Kanthimathi had accompanied her husband Sri Keshava , to Parathasarathy temple in Chennai, performed the yajna , and begot  Sri Ramanujacharya. This was the state of affair thousand years ago.

Comment: It is considered inauspicious if women of South India covered their head or face with anything like veil..Women for decades were honoured with turmeric ,betel leaf and banana in wedding fests.The situation stated in Q could've been a regional constraint , and a societial obligation. so it may not ve any thing to do with shaastras in broad spectrum. Btw , Devi Satyabhama was a warrior lady.

Comment: *"so the bride weeps at her wedding because she would never ever visit her paternal home and see her mother or father ever again after the wedding, not even on any special occasion."* - where did you hear this ? the bride & groom visit bride's parents during important festivals, and it is usually bride's mom who helps during her first pregnancy.

Comment: *"Women enter into the house on four shoulders (i.e on a Palanquin at the time of marriage) and go outside of the house on four shoulders (i.e at the time of their death)"* - yes - in Tamil, such a chaste woman is called **'padi thaanda patni'** - wife who doesn't cross steps (of house entrance). it is to protect both their eyes from falling (with lust) on stranger men, and to protect stranger men's eyes and falling on them. because even to look with desire is similar to adultery.

Comment: @Athrey - both men and women have a rule. wife should not gaze upon any man other than her husband (only 1 husband allowed). men should not gaze upon wife of any other man (multiple wives allowed). whichever religion/society upholds this rule will eventually dominate and survive over a religion/society which doesn't (temporary invasions not withholding). shaving & covering the head is required for widows (and still followed by orthodox brahmins today). covering the face out of fear/modesty/shyness is allowed in north india (rajasthan) due to repeated invasions.

Comment: @Narasimham - *"Today women have freedom to work outside home."* - they also have freedom to have premarital sex and commit adultery. Do you support these ? If not, why are you restricting their freedoms like Taliban ? if people in afghanistan breathe air, you will stop breathing too ? this juvenile fetish to blindly differentiate hinduism from abrahamic religions will cause downfall. if muslims avoid alcohol, we should start drinking ?

Comment: @Narasimham -  protecting women's chastity in a society a shared responsibility between men and women. if men are unable to look at women without lust, then the women should cover up or stay inside. the the men are able to look at women without lust, then the women need not. however, if the men are unable, and the women don't cover up - that is state of the West. and librandus wanting to ape the west are slowly bringing this shameful practice into India too.

Comment: "Devi Satyabhama was a warrior lady..." - incorrect as satyabhama (and kaikeyi) were not independent warriors. They only accompanied their husband in war.